# retrieving data from flash builder http service

Tags: flash-builder

I am just learning my way around Flash builder and need some help.

I have set up a http service to send sign in data to a server and retrieve a token as a response.

I have set up the service, run the test to make sure it working. What I Am trying to do is store the token in a variable.

This is where i am getting lost.

The code that has been generated looks like:

```
<![CDATA[
        protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            signinResult.token = signin.signin(/*Enter value(s) for */ username.text, password.text);
        }
    ]]>

</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="signinResult"/>
    <signin:Signin id="signin"/>
```

what I dont know is how to gather the returned vales and put them into a variable for later use.

Most examples seem to show the data being attached to a list view etc. but I am just wanting to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a resulthandler to your CallResponder.

```
<valueObjects:VerifyResult id="verifyResult"/> 
<s:CallResponder id="signinResult" result="VerifysigninResult_resultHandeler(event)" />

<![CDATA[
    protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        signinResult.token = signin.signin(/*Enter value(s) for */ username.text,   password.text);
    }

     protected function VerifysigninResult_resultHandeler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
      verifyResult = signinResult.lastResult[0] as VerifyResult;
      // no you can access the the return if you Configured the Return Types in the Dataservice
     verifyResult.MyReturn;
    }  
]]>
```